# Why if $a = kb + c$ then $a \text{ mod } b = c \text{ mod } b$

Tags: number-theory, congruences

Here is a very simple question in number theory that I can't prove it. If $a = kb + c$, then I would like to know why the following is true ($a,b,c,k \in \mathbb{Z}$):

$$a \bmod b = c \bmod b$$

And another question, Why if $a+b \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ then $a \equiv -b \pmod{p}$

Comment: The usual way to write down "a mod b = c mod b" is : $$a\equiv c\ (\ mod\ b\ )$$ and it is equivalent to $$b|a-c$$

Comment: Second question : You simply subtract $b$ on both sides.

Comment: So, is  $kb + c \equiv c \, (\text{mod} \, b)$?

Comment: Yes, this is the case.

Comment: @Peter for the second one, am I allowed to subtract?

Comment: Yes, $-b$ can be seen as an addition of the element $-b$.

Comment: In short, an equivalence remains true, if you add an element, subtract an element or multiply with an element on both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $b\ne0$ (which is needed for doing the “$\!\bmod b$” operation), $x\bmod b$ is the *unique* integer $r$ such that

1. $x=bq+r$, for some integer $q$,
2. $0\le r<|b|$

It is a well known fact that such an $r$ exists and is unique.

Now, suppose $a=bk+c$ and write $c=bq+r$, with $0\le r<|b|$. Then also
$$
a=b(k+q)+r
$$
thereby proving that
$$
a\bmod b=c\bmod b
$$
by the uniqueness of the remainder $r$ stated above.

---

For the second part, note that $x\equiv y\pmod{n}$ means that $x-y$ is divisible by $n$. Then use the fact that $a+b=a-(-b)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. in the first question, you write $c = bq + r$, what if $b > c$? is it still true? because all we know is $$a = kb + c$$, but we don't know if $c$ is greater then $b$ or not

Comment: @Drupalist $0$ is an integer; nowhere it is said that $q>0$.